# Where do I put the date validation function?

Tags: python, validation

I have date validation function `check_dates()` to check if start date entered is before end date and I want to use this in the `add_leave()` function that adds the leave to the calendar. If the date is not valid I don't want to print leave confirmed.

Where should I put `check_dates()`? `check_dates()` raises a value error when start date is after end date.

```
def add_leave(self):
    data_l = []
    self.check_dates(start_date, end_date)
    try:
        with open ("data.csv","r") as data:
            reader = csv.reader(data)
            user_id = self.user_id_validation()
            for row in reader:
                if row[0] == user_id:
                    leave = self.leave_option.get()
                    start_date = "-".join([self.start_date_entry.get()])
                    end_date = "-".join([self.end_date_entry.get()])
                    row.append(leave)
                    row.append(start_date)
                    row.append(end_date)
                data_l.append(row)
        with open ("data.csv","w", newline='') as data:
            writer = csv.writer(data)
            writer.writerows(data_l)

        print("Leave Confirmed")

    except:
        print("Leave has not been confirmed.")
```

This doesn't work:

```
def add_leave(self):
    data_l = []
    self.check_dates(start_date, end_date)
    try:
        with open ("data.csv","r") as data:
            reader = csv.reader(data)
            user_id = self.user_id_validation()
            for row in reader:
                if row[0] == user_id:
                    leave = self.leave_option.get()
                    start_date = "-".join([self.start_date_entry.get()])
                    end_date = "-".join([self.end_date_entry.get()])
                    try:
                        if self.check_dates(start_date,end_date):
                                raise ValueError
                        return(start_date,end_date)
                    except:
                          messagebox.showinfo("Invalid Input", "Please select valid start and end dates.\nThe start date should be earlier than the end date.")

                    row.append(leave)
                    row.append(start_date)
                    row.append(end_date)
                data_l.append(row)
        with open ("data.csv","w", newline='') as data:
            writer = csv.writer(data)
            writer.writerows(data_l)

        print("Leave Confirmed")

    except:
        print("Leave has not been confirmed.")
```

Comment: Please fix indentation

Comment: I've done it now

Comment: Your check_date function should not raise an error in the case of start date that is earlier than the end date - it's a possible case that you should handle in the regular flow of your code. The function should return a boolean, indicating that the date are ok or not. You should keep the excpetions to cases that you cannot  handle by yourself.

Comment: I tried it (in the question) and it still prints the confirmation message.

Comment: @amsi_25 I'm sorry but your code has a lot of issues and despite being pointed out you are not updating the approach. Why are you trying to raise an error while parsing a CSV file? You should wait until all the rows are processed. You are also using [try..except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) in an odd way, returning from a try..except in the try block. If you are parsing the whole csv, why `messagebox` is needed?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming check_dates() returns true if the date is valid and false otherwise. You can check it after getting the start_date and end_date

```
def add_leave(self):
    data_l = []
    
    try:
        with open ("data.csv","r") as data:
            reader = csv.reader(data)
            user_id = self.user_id_validation()
            for row in reader:
                if row[0] == user_id:
                    leave = self.leave_option.get()
                    start_date = "-".join([self.start_date_entry.get()])
                    end_date = "-".join([self.end_date_entry.get()])
                    # Adding the date validation
                    if(!self.check_dates(start_date, end_date))
                        raise Exception("Invalid date!!")
                    row.append(leave)
                    row.append(start_date)
                    row.append(end_date)
                data_l.append(row)
        with open ("data.csv","w", newline='') as data:
            writer = csv.writer(data)
            writer.writerows(data_l)
        

        print("Leave Confirmed")

    except:
       print("Leave has not been confirmed.")
```

Comment: The check date function raises a value error if start_date>end_date and it prints invalid input. So adding it after start and end date still prints the confirmation message.

Comment: "it prints invalid input" - Are you handling the exception inside check_dates() and then printing it?

Comment: Yes exception is handled within check_dates()

Comment: From what I understand, though the exception is thrown, it is getting handled in the method itself i.e. not getting propagated outside of the method, as a result, check_dates() is neither returning anything nor throwing an exception. Instead of raising a value error, you can try returning false if start_date>end_date and true otherwise.

Comment: If possible pls share check_dates() implementation

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional statement within your `try` after `if row[0] == user_id:` that raises an exception [List of Built-in Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).

```
def add_leave(self):
data_l = []
self.check_dates(start_date, end_date)
try:
    with open ("data.csv","r") as data:
        reader = csv.reader(data)
        user_id = self.user_id_validation()
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] == user_id:
                leave = self.leave_option.get()
                start_date = "-".join([self.start_date_entry.get()])
                end_date = "-".join([self.end_date_entry.get()])

                #Check here 
                if(!self.check_dates(start_date, end_date)):
                    raise ValueError('Start date entered is before the end date')

                row.append(leave)
                row.append(start_date)
                row.append(end_date)
            data_l.append(row)
    with open ("data.csv","w", newline='') as data:
        writer = csv.writer(data)
        writer.writerows(data_l)

    print("Leave Confirmed")

except Exception:
   print("Leave has not been confirmed.")

#Handle Error
except ValueError as error:
   print("Error: "+repr(error))
```

Comment: I tried this after the start and end date where I added the following: ```#Adding in the date validation
                        try:
                            if self.check_dates(start_date,end_date) == FALSE:
                                raise ValueError
                            return(start_date,end_date)
                        except:
                            messagebox.showinfo("Invalid Input", "Please select valid start and end dates.\nThe start date should be earlier than the end date.") ``` And it still printed out the leave confirmation message. Will add above!

Comment: Little hard to follow the formatting of your comment, although, I do know since your check_date method returns True or False, you don't have to do an additional check if True == FALSE or False == FALSE. You can just leave it at `if self.check_dates(start_date,end_date):`

Comment: I tried that with what you said (added in the question) and it still prints out the leave confirmation message.

Comment: Just looked at your edit on your first post, you shouldn't need to create a second try block, the purpose of `raise ValueError('Start date entered is before the end date')` is to break out and skip over the rest of the code in the current try block (aka skip over `print("Leave Confirmed")`).

Answer (score 0):

Just put it inside check dates. before you check relationship between `start` and `end` validate that `start` and `end` are valid dates to begin with.